# Local.ERROR: Route [login] not defined. Laravel Problem

Tags: php, laravel, web, xampp

Strange thing happening in my code! I created a website with Laravel like 2 years ago and it was working just fine but now that I tried to open it and see it again, I'm facing some problems, the views work so fine before logging in or signing up to the system but ever since I sign up or log in, all pages go suddenly blank, I'm so confused and I can't figure out the problem is where exactly, also when I check my DB, a new user been added to the table 'users' according to the infos I signed up with, so it works but it doesn't show me the system.

Here's a part of my code:

```
               RegisterController

  public function create()
   {
     return view('/register');
   }

     public function store(Request $request)
   {
$user = new User;
$user->name = $request->name;
$user->email = $request->email;
$user->password = bcrypt($request->password);

if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    $user->photo = $request->photo->store('avatar');
}

if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $user->image = $request->image->store('avatar');
}


$user->save();

$user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Elève')->first());

auth()->login($user);

return redirect('/');
   }
```

routes

```
   Route::get('/register', 'RegisterController@create');
   Route::post('/register', 'RegisterController@store');
```

I checked Laravel.log for errors and I found this error:

```
 [2018-05-24 09:53:59] local.ERROR: Route [login] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\education 
  finale\resources\views\layouts\edu.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\education 
 finale\resources\views\layouts\edu.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Route 
   [login] not defined. (View: C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\education finale\
     esources\\views\\layouts\\edu.blade.php) (View: C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\education finale\
      esources\\views\\layouts\\edu.blade.php) at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\education 
       finale\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\UrlGenerator.php:370, 
  ErrorException(code: 0): Route [login] not defined. (View: C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\education finale\
  esources\\views\\layouts\\edu.blade.php) at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\education 
  finale\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\UrlGenerator.php:370, 
  InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Route [login] not defined. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\education 
 finale\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\UrlGenerator.php:370)
  [stacktrace]
```

There is something else, last time (two years ago) I was running xampp from my disk drive C, and now I'm running it from my disk drive D maybe that's the problem how do i change the path?

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1):

The error provided shows you which file to look at:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\education\finale\resources\views\layouts\edu.blade.php
```

In this file, there is likely a line which has:

```
{{ route('login') }}
```

As in your routes files, you do not have a `login` route defined, this error is being thrown.

The login route is usually created automatically by the `Auth` facade. So in your routes file, it would be expected to have:

```
Auth::routes();
```

You can see which routes have been registered and their names by running `php artisan route:list` in your Command Prompt whilst in the Laravel root directory.

To resolve this, you'll either need to redefine the `login` route, or remove the reference to it from the view.